# MySql char(128) and above

Tags: mysql

So I am learning about MySql's `char()` function and tried the following:

`SELECT CHAR(128);` which should've been Ç.

```
+-----------+
| CHAR(128) |
+-----------+
| ?          |
+-----------+
```

MySql docs don't really say [much](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char).

Comment: Maybe the character is not printable in your console

Comment: i guess it depends which text encoding your database / table / column uses. The Mysql GUI of your choice should be able to show you that. If you know the encoding then you can look up the table.

Comment: This depends on the charter-set and in the DB level you need to check which character-set is set. If you use `SELECT convert(CHAR(128) USING latin1);`  you should get `€` so you need to use convert to your character set.